# Peform deletion of rows for all files in a directory

Tags: bash, parsing

Currently I am trying to delete the last two rows of every file in a specific directory I am working on. I know how to delete the last two rows in it:

```
head -n -2 myfile.txt
```

but how can I perform that task for all files in my dir without retyping it and listing filenames .....

Comment: Use `for file in dir/*; do echo $file; ...` loop or `find` command (which can have a command as argument, to execute on each matching file). Anyway, questions like this are more suitable at unix.stackexchange.com I think.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find` and do it one by one:

```
find -exec head -n -2 {} \;
```

this line use `find` to find out all the files in the directory, and then execute(`-exec`) a command `head -n -2 {}` where `{}` means the filename found, and the `\;` at last is essential, it means do it one by one.

UPDATE:

i didn't found the way you said to use `head` is actually not writing to the file,if you want to delete the last two lines, that is not as easy, one liner could be subtle:

```
find -exec bash -c 'c=`wc -l {} | awk '"'{print \$1}'"'`; sed -i "$((c-1)),${c}d" {}' \;
```

sounds better to use a for loop:

```
for file in folder/*; do
    c=`wc -l $file | awk '{print $1}'`
    sed -i "$((c-1)),${c}d" $file
done
```

Comment: somehow this only prints loads of the files to the standard out ...I thought I dont have to pipe anything ? or redirect something?

Comment: think my problem is whether I need to create a new file with these two rows less or wehther there is anotherway?